# Adding a small vector to corresponding values in large df

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and a small vector, and want to add the elements of the vector corresponding to the specified filename_id in the dataset.

A scaled down version of my df:

```
 V1     V2
1  1 f1.csv
2  2 f1.csv
3  3 f1.csv
4  4 f2.csv
5  5 f2.csv
6  6 f3.csv

vec <- c(1,4,3)
```

So I want to add the first element of vec to all the "f1.csv", the second to all the f2.csv.

What is the smartest way to do this in r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
df$V3 <- vec[factor(df$V2, levels = unique(df$V2))]
df

#  V1     V2 V3
#1  1 f1.csv  1
#2  2 f1.csv  1
#3  3 f1.csv  1
#4  4 f2.csv  4
#5  5 f2.csv  4
#6  6 f3.csv  3
```

Similarly, using `match`

```
df$V3 <- vec[match(df$V2, unique(df$V2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may extract the numbers for subsetting `vec` using `gsub` and regular expressions.

```
dat <- transform(dat, V3=vec[as.numeric(gsub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", V2))])
dat
#   V1     V2 V3
# 1  1 f1.csv  1
# 2  2 f1.csv  1
# 3  3 f1.csv  1
# 4  4 f2.csv  4
# 5  5 f2.csv  4
# 6  6 f3.csv  3
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = 1:6, V2 = c("f1.csv", "f1.csv", "f1.csv", 
"f2.csv", "f2.csv", "f3.csv")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

vec <- c(1, 4, 3)
```